# C# IPC Between BHO and Service

Tags: c#, ipc, uac, bho

I can't seem to find a way to communicate between my IE C# BHO and a C# console app running as SYSTEM.

So far I have tried using Remoting and EventWaitHandle, but both give me "access denied" errors when I have UAC turned on the default setting in Win 7.

I have been able to have a console app that communicates with the service using both Remoting and EventWaitHandle.

I need a way to share data between the two processes with UAC on, what are my options?

Comment: It is a back-door to a privilege elevation.  A door that UAC was designed to close.

Comment: I don't think UAC could prevent you from having the C# console app listening on a port (accepting local connections only) and having the BHO connect to it via TCP/UDP

Comment: I know almost nothing about managed BHOs however, you can host a WCF service in the console application, using `netNamedPipesBinding`. That's a pretty secure binding and only works within the same computer. Maybe you can add a service reference to your BHO project, pointing to the console service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reviewing [Understanding and Working in Protected Mode Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462.aspx). There's a section about half-way down which states:

> **Note**  The best practice is run your application with low integrity if you are communicating with Protected mode. Otherwise use only secure forms of interprocess communication (IPC), such as remote procedure calls (RPC), to communicate between Protected mode and a higher integrity process.

Essentially, anything running in an IE "Protected Mode" process is very restricted "sandbox". Whilst [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/PMSurvivalGuide.aspx#enableipc) targets C++/COM, you should be able to apply the principles it explains to writing something in managed code although it's likely you'll have to P/Invoke to achieve this.